# Finding the sum of a column that contains a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this select query:

```
SELECT 
    total,   
    COALESCE(total - Lag(total)OVER(ORDER BY total), 0) AS dif_total
FROM   ( select count(*) as total
    FROM
         tbl_person
    left join
         tbl_census
    on
          tbl_census.person_id = tbl_person.person_id
    group by extract(year from tbl_census.date)
    ) abc
```

Is there a way I could find the sum of the column dif_total?
I can't use the Sum() because it contains a window function.

I tried saving the column to an array because I figure maybe I could call the function and convert the array to a column then use Sum().
But I messed it up.

Here is my query for the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function growth() Returns int[] as $$
declare total2 integer[];  
BEGIN  
      SELECT
           total,
           COALESCE(total - Lag(total)OVER(ORDER BY total), 0) into total2
      FROM
           ( select count(*) as total
            from
                 tbl_person
            group by extract(year from bdate)
            ) abc ;
RETURN total2;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function query runs successfully and does not show any warning or error but I think I was doing it wrong because when I try to SELECT it it will say

> Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

I'm very new in using stored function in postgre.
What changes should I do to my function to work?
Or what are the other ways for me to sum the column dif_total above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap it with another select?

```
SELECT total,sum(dif_total) as total_2
FROM ( YOUR QUERY HERE...)
GROUP BY total
```